# How can I install Wine in 15.04 when there are unmet dependencies?

Tags: wine, dependencies, 15.04

When I try to install Wine in Ubuntu 15.04, I get the following message:

```
>sudo apt-get install wine
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed or
                 wine1.7 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have looked for solutions and done the usual `sudo apt-get -f install`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` without success. What should I do?

---

The output of `sudo apt-get -f install` is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

The output of `sudo apt-get upgrade` is as follows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  doxygen
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 1 not to upgrade.
```

---

EDIT: Following [a suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/624854/204323) by @Serphiroth, I ran the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

This resulted in the following message:

```
>sudo apt-get install wine1.7
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.38-0ubuntu1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

An attempt at installing `wine1.7-i386` results in the following message:

```
>sudo apt-get install wine1.7-i386
checking for actuality of program wine1.7-i386...
instating wine1.7-i386...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Depends: libldap-2.4-2:i386 (>= 2.4.7) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libasound2-plugins:i386 but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libcups2:i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

EDIT: Following [another suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/624846/how-can-i-install-wine-in-15-04-when-there-are-unmet-dependencies/624876#comment885833_624854) by @Serphiroth, I ran the following:

```
>sudo apt-get install wine1.7 wine1.7-i386"=1.7.4-0ubuntu4"
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version ‘1.7.4-0ubuntu4’ for ‘wine1.7-i386:i386’ was not found
```

Following [a suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/624876/204323) by @A.B., I ran the following:

```
>sudo aptitude install wine
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} 
  libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} 
  libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcups2:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} libgcrypt20:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} 
  libgif4:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{ab} libgnutls-deb0-28:i386{a} libgnutls26:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} 
  libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed2:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{ab} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} 
  libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} 
  libltdl7:i386{a} libmpg123-0:i386{a} libnettle4:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} libosmesa6{a} libosmesa6:i386{a} 
  libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} libsasl2-modules:i386{a} 
  libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} 
  libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} 
  libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} 
  p11-kit-modules:i386{a} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6{a} 
  wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 76 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 155 MB of archives. After unpacking 505 MB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjack-jackd2-0:i386 : Conflicts: libjack-0.116 which is a virtual package.
                         Conflicts: libjack0 but 1:0.124.1+20140122git5013bed0-3 is installed.
 libjack0 : Conflicts: libjack-0.116:i386 which is a virtual package.
 libgmp10 : Breaks: libgmp10:i386 (!= 2:6.0.0+dfsg-6~ppa1) but 2:6.0.0+dfsg-4build1 is to be installed.
 libgmp10:i386 : Breaks: libgmp10 (!= 2:6.0.0+dfsg-4build1) but 2:6.0.0+dfsg-6~ppa1 is installed.
open: 59; closed: 907; defer: 31; conflict: 38                                                                     .The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

      Keep the following packages at their current version: 
1)      libasound2-plugins:i386 [Not Installed]             
2)      libcups2:i386 [Not Installed]                       
3)      libgmp10:i386 [Not Installed]                       
4)      libgnutls-deb0-28:i386 [Not Installed]              
5)      libhogweed2:i386 [Not Installed]                    
6)      libjack-jackd2-0:i386 [Not Installed]               
7)      libldap-2.4-2:i386 [Not Installed]                  
8)      wine [Not Installed]                                
9)      wine1.6 [Not Installed]                             
10)     wine1.6-amd64 [Not Installed]                       
11)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [Not Installed]                   

      Leave the following dependencies unresolved:          
12)     winetricks recommends wine                          
13)     wine1.6-i386:i386 recommends libasound2-plugins:i386


Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]
```

I have looked through the various solutions presented (by selecting `n`), but I really don't know enough to proceed without guidance.

Comment: Did you try installing it from the repositories ?

Comment: @Serphiroth Yes, I just did the usual ```sudo apt-get install wine```. I have tried your suggestion of installing from the Wine PPA since (without success).

Comment: why don't you use the software center to install wine?

Answer (score 2):

This likely can't be resolved in 1 simple answer but for starters your issue, or one of,  comes from a ppa that seems to have been removed

https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/programs-ppa

It used to have trusty packages - ex. https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/ubuntu/programs-ppa/+build/6277936

That is causing this issue

`libgmp10 : Breaks: libgmp10:i386 (!= 2:6.0.0+dfsg-6~ppa1) but 2:6.0.0+dfsg-4build1 is to be installed.
 libgmp10:i386 : Breaks: libgmp10 (!= 2:6.0.0+dfsg-4build1) but 2:6.0.0+dfsg-6~ppa1 is installed.`

To ck. run - `apt-cache policy libgmp10 libgmp10:i386` , both available/installed should be same version & not from that crappy ppa

So if `2:6.0.0+dfsg-6~ppa1` comes up in apt-cache as available then open Software & Updates > Other & remove the associated ppa, update your sources, then try again. If the ppa i386 package shows as installed then remove it.

Otherwise you'll need to identify any packages from that ppa & remove and or replace with Ubuntu ones

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem:

## # apt-get install wine1.6-i386

Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
Nie udało się zainstalować niektórych pakietów. Może to oznaczać,
że zażądano niemożliwej sytuacji lub użyto dystrybucji niestabilnej,
w której niektóre pakiety nie zostały jeszcze utworzone lub przeniesione
z katalogu Incoming ("Przychodzące").
Następujące informacje mogą pomóc rozwiązać sytuację:

Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności:
 wine1.6-i386:i386 : Wymaga: libglu1-mesa:i386 ale nie zostanie zainstalowany lub
                             libglu1:i386
                     Poleca: libosmesa6:i386 ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
E: Nie udało się naprawić problemów, zatrzymano uszkodzone pakiety.

## apt-get install wine1.7-i386

Czytanie list pakietów... Gotowe
Budowanie drzewa zależności
Odczyt informacji o stanie... Gotowe
Nie udało się zainstalować niektórych pakietów. Może to oznaczać,
że zażądano niemożliwej sytuacji lub użyto dystrybucji niestabilnej,
w której niektóre pakiety nie zostały jeszcze utworzone lub przeniesione
z katalogu Incoming ("Przychodzące").
Następujące informacje mogą pomóc rozwiązać sytuację:

Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności:
 wine1.7-i386:i386 : Wymaga: libglu1-mesa:i386 ale nie zostanie zainstalowany lub
                             libglu1:i386
                     Poleca: libgnutls26:i386 ale nie da się go zainstalować
                     Poleca: libosmesa6:i386 ale nie zostanie zainstalowany
E: Nie udało się naprawić problemów, zatrzymano uszkodzone pakiety.

## # aptitude install wine

Następujące NOWE pakiety zostaną zainstalowane:
  fonts-horai-umefont{a} fonts-unfonts-core{a} gcc-4.9-base:i386{a} gcc-5-base:i386{a} gnome-exe-thumbnailer{a} 
  libasn1-8-heimdal:i386{a} libasound2:i386{a} libasound2-plugins:i386{a} libasyncns0:i386{a} libavahi-client3:i386{a} 
  libavahi-common-data:i386{a} libavahi-common3:i386{a} libc6:i386{a} libcapi20-3{a} libcapi20-3:i386{a} libcomerr2:i386{a} 
  libcups2:i386{a} libdb5.3:i386{a} libdbus-1-3:i386{a} libdrm-intel1:i386{ab} libdrm-nouveau2:i386{ab} libdrm-radeon1:i386{ab} 
  libdrm2:i386{ab} libedit2:i386{a} libelf1:i386{a} libexif12:i386{a} libexpat1:i386{a} libffi6:i386{a} libflac8:i386{a} 
  libfontconfig1:i386{a} libfreetype6:i386{a} libgcc1:i386{a} libgcrypt20:i386{a} libgd3:i386{a} libgif4:i386{a} 
  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386{ab} libgl1-mesa-glx:i386{ab} libglapi-mesa:i386{ab} libglib2.0-0:i386{a} libglu1-mesa:i386{a} libgmp10:i386{a} 
  libgnutls-deb0-28:i386{a} libgpg-error0:i386{a} libgphoto2-6:i386{a} libgphoto2-port10:i386{a} libgpm2:i386{a} 
  libgssapi-krb5-2:i386{a} libgssapi3-heimdal:i386{a} libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386{a} libgstreamer0.10-0:i386{a} 
  libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386{a} libheimbase1-heimdal:i386{a} libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386{a} libhogweed2:i386{a} libhx509-5-heimdal:i386{a} 
  libice6:i386{a} libicu52:i386{a} libieee1284-3:i386{a} libjack-jackd2-0:i386{a} libjbig0:i386{a} libjpeg-turbo8:i386{a} 
  libjpeg8:i386{a} libjson-c2:i386{a} libk5crypto3:i386{a} libkeyutils1:i386{a} libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386{a} libkrb5-3:i386{a} 
  libkrb5support0:i386{a} liblcms2-2:i386{a} libldap-2.4-2:i386{a} libllvm3.6:i386{a} libltdl7:i386{a} liblzma5:i386{a} 
  libmpg123-0:i386{a} libncurses5:i386{a} libnettle4:i386{a} libodbc1{a} libogg0:i386{a} libopenal1:i386{a} liborc-0.4-0:i386{a} 
  libosmesa6{ab} libosmesa6:i386{a} libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386{a} libp11-kit0:i386{a} libpciaccess0:i386{a} libpcre3:i386{a} 
  libpng12-0:i386{a} libpulse0:i386{a} libroken18-heimdal:i386{a} libsamplerate0:i386{a} libsane:i386{a} libsasl2-2:i386{a} 
  libsasl2-modules:i386{a} libsasl2-modules-db:i386{a} libselinux1:i386{a} libsm6:i386{a} libsndfile1:i386{a} libspeexdsp1:i386{a} 
  libsqlite3-0:i386{a} libssl1.0.0:i386{a} libstdc++6:i386{a} libsystemd0:i386{a} libtasn1-6:i386{a} libtiff5:i386{a} libtinfo5:i386{a} 
  libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0:i386{a} libudev1:i386{a} libusb-1.0-0:i386{a} libuuid1:i386{a} libv4l-0:i386{a} libv4lconvert0:i386{a} 
  libvorbis0a:i386{a} libvorbisenc2:i386{a} libvpx1:i386{a} libwind0-heimdal:i386{a} libwrap0:i386{a} libx11-6:i386{a} 
  libx11-xcb1:i386{a} libxau6:i386{a} libxcb-dri2-0:i386{a} libxcb-dri3-0:i386{a} libxcb-glx0:i386{a} libxcb-present0:i386{a} 
  libxcb-sync1:i386{a} libxcb1:i386{a} libxcomposite1:i386{a} libxcursor1:i386{a} libxdamage1:i386{a} libxdmcp6:i386{a} 
  libxext6:i386{a} libxfixes3:i386{a} libxi6:i386{a} libxinerama1:i386{a} libxml2:i386{a} libxpm4:i386{a} libxrandr2:i386{a} 
  libxrender1:i386{a} libxshmfence1:i386{a} libxslt1.1:i386{a} libxt6:i386{a} libxxf86vm1:i386{a} ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386{a} 
  odbcinst{a} odbcinst1debian2{a} p11-kit-modules:i386{a} p7zip{a} unixodbc{a} wine wine-gecko2.21{a} wine-gecko2.21:i386{a} 
  wine-mono0.0.8{a} wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64{a} wine1.6-i386:i386{a} winetricks{a} zlib1g:i386{a} 
0 pakietów aktualizowanych, 156 instalowanych, 0 do usunięcia i 0 nieaktualizowanych.
Do pobrania 189 MB archiwów. Zajęte po rozpakowaniu: 628 MB.
Następujące pakiety mają niespełnione zależności:
 libdrm-intel1 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-intel1:i386 (!= 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 2.4.60-2.
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-intel1 (!= 2.4.60-2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic.
 libgl1-mesa-dri : Narusza zależności: libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 (!= 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2.
 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 : Narusza zależności: libgl1-mesa-dri (!= 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic.
 libdrm-radeon1 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-radeon1:i386 (!= 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 2.4.60-2.
 libdrm-radeon1:i386 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-radeon1 (!= 2.4.60-2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic.
 libglapi-mesa : Narusza zależności: libglapi-mesa:i386 (!= 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2.
 libglapi-mesa:i386 : Narusza zależności: libglapi-mesa (!= 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic.
 libgl1-mesa-glx : Narusza zależności: libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 (!= 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2.
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Narusza zależności: libgl1-mesa-glx (!= 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic.
 libosmesa6 : Wymaga: libglapi-mesa (= 10.5.9-2ubuntu1~vivid2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 10.6.0~git20150423.125574d1-0ubuntu0ricotz~utopic.
 libdrm-nouveau2 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-nouveau2:i386 (!= 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 2.4.60-2.
 libdrm-nouveau2:i386 : Narusza zależności: libdrm-nouveau2 (!= 2.4.60-2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic.
 libdrm2 : Narusza zależności: libdrm2:i386 (!= 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic) ale zaplanowana jest instalacja wersji 2.4.60-2.
 libdrm2:i386 : Narusza zależności: libdrm2 (!= 2.4.60-2) ale zainstalowana jest wersja 2.4.60+git20150416.0d78b37b-0ubuntu0ricotz2~utopic.
Następujące działania rozwiążą problemy z zależnościami:

```
  Zatrzymanie bieżących wersji następujących pakietów:
```

1)      libdrm-intel1:i386 [niezainstalowany]    // niezainstalowany = not installed
2)      libdrm-nouveau2:i386 [niezainstalowany]
3)      libdrm-radeon1:i386 [niezainstalowany]
4)      libdrm2:i386 [niezainstalowany]
5)      libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 [niezainstalowany]
6)      libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 [niezainstalowany]
7)      libglapi-mesa:i386 [niezainstalowany]
8)      libglu1-mesa:i386 [niezainstalowany]
9)      libosmesa6 [niezainstalowany]
10)     libosmesa6:i386 [niezainstalowany]
11)     wine [niezainstalowany]
12)     wine1.6 [niezainstalowany]
13)     wine1.6-amd64 [niezainstalowany]
14)     wine1.6-i386:i386 [niezainstalowany]

```
  Pozostawienie następujących problemów z zależnościami:
```

15)     winetricks poleca wine

Zaakceptować rozwiązanie? [Y/n/q/?] Y
Nie zostaną zainstalowane, zaktualizowane ani usunięte żadne pakiety.
0 pakietów aktualizowanych, 0 instalowanych, 0 do usunięcia i 0 nieaktualizowanych.
Do pobrania 0 B archiwów. Zajęte po rozpakowaniu: 0 B.

## Then i did:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
```

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -s

if everything is OK:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

apt-get install wine1.7

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. Your instructions are the only thing that got wine to install (Ubuntu 15.04 amd64 radeon).  I can finally watch NHK World Live using Win Firefox and Adobe Flash. Where did you find this solution?

Comment: Well i had same problem thats why i started to search.. I found some on google or another quesion on this and other forums. Tried.. and it works for me.

Comment: It's sufficient to add the PPA, run `apt-get update`, `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt-get install wine`.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by going into Software & Updates and enabling the community repositories, then install the ppa, update and install wine.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -2):

Try these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7
```

The [source](https://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Comment: Hey there. Thank you for your suggestion. I ran those commands, but it wasn't successful. I've detailed the output in an edit to my post, but it mentions not having the dependency ```wine1.7-i386```.

Comment: Try these commande : sudo apt-get install wine1.7 wine1.7-i386"=1.7.4-0ubuntu4"

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't seem to be able to find that package, though.