# Dependecies error when trying to insatll wine

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dependencies

When I do

```
 sudo apt-get install wine
```

I get all this errors

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine : Depends: wine1.6 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

When I try to install `sudo apt-get install wine1.6` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu10)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I kept trying to install every package they gave me but it drove me into an infinite loop, I tried doing : `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

But the same problem, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

1) Open synaptic package manager and repair broken paquets
2) Open terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y wine1.7
```

You can install wine 1.8

```
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.8
```

Or wine 1.9

```
sudo apt-get -y install wine1.9
```

Comment: Same dependency error :/

Comment: try to install wine from synaptic

Comment: When I try to install it they say fix the broken packages first when I go Edit->fix broken packages I get this http://pastebin.com/tqTdw32Q

Comment: Run sudo apt-get install -f  for more info : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1594933

Comment: Same problem :/

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/666174/498780